# Как заменить все ключи словаря на их значения в списке в python

Tags: python

Допустим, у меня есть словарь:

```
dict={'a':'b','c':'d'}
```

И список:

```
List=['a','qwe','c']
```

Далее происходит какая-то магия,
и все ключи словаря dict заменяются на их значения в List.
А затем выводим List:

```
print(List)
```

На выходе я хочу получить

```
['b','qwe','d']
```

Как это сделать?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `List = [dict.get(x, x) for x in List]`

Comment: Хотите использовать встроенные типы как названия переменных - либо добавляйте подчёркивание в конце, либо одну букву выкидывайте: `dict_` и `list_` либо `dct` и `lst`. А большие буквы в питоне используются в названиях классов.

Comment: andreymal, чио такое x ?

Comment: @Maks Это переменная внутри цикла в списковом сокращении

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо большое, работает!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так...

```py
l = [d.get(x, x) for x in l]
print(l)
```

Comment: что за месиво с этими однобуквенными переменными...

Comment: @PeterKolosov, согласен на половину. `x` на месте, `l` нет. `l` плохо использовать из-за путаницы с единицей. Контейнеры хорошо называть развернуто (`list_`, `lst`, `seq`, `it`). Однобуквенные переменные циклов - нормально. У них нет самостоятельного значения.

Comment: @PeterKolosov `dict` - переписывать не хорошо, а `List` с большой буквы - может казаться классом а не списком

Comment: @anton Ну это же не значит, что нужно использовать однобуквенные переменные. Ведь мы можем использовать не только эти названия, верно?